# How to rotate using difference-list in Prolog

Tags: prolog, difference-lists

Using difference-lists,How to rotate a given list by moving the first two elements to the end of the list, so that [a,b,c,d] becomes [c,d,a,b].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotating a list to the right (Prolog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081912/rotating-a-list-to-the-right-prolog)

Comment: Or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28921904/772868).

Answer (score 1):

If you're being *provided* with a difference list, then can use:

```
?- L = [a,b,c,d,e,f|R], L = [H1, H2|T], R = [H1, H2].
T = [c,d,e,f,a,b].
```

Answer (score 0):

As a DCG (more human-friendly than difference lists), in swi-prolog:

```
% For remainder/1
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

% Show lists of codes nicely
:- portray_text(true).

rotate2, Rem, [E1, E2] --> [E1, E2], remainder(Rem).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- phrase(rotate2, `abcdef`, R).
R = `cdefab`.
```

Alternatively, if you need the tail also:

```
rotate2_tail([A, B|T]) --> T, [A, B].
```

```
?- phrase(rotate2_tail(`abcdef`), L, R).
L = `cdefab|R`.
```

As a third method (note that there is no actual *difference list* specified in the question):

```
?- L = [a,b,c,d,e,f], L = [H1, H2|T], append(T, [H1, H2], L2).
L2 = [c,d,e,f,a,b].
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to know using difference-list  how to rotate the given list